# Let A be an m×n matrix with rank m.

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a post that answered the question in a way I didn't find intuitive. 
I want to prove that for any $m \times n$ matrix $A$ of Rank $m$, there exists some $n \times m$ matrix $B$ s.t. $AB=I_m$.

I've tried this by two approaches. Since Rank $A$ is $m$, the matrix is surjective. From there, I didn't really get anywhere. What I tried was constructing an isomorphism, but I couldn't find any way to get a $B$ for which $AB$ is invertible.

My second approach was by trying to get some matrix $D$, for which $AD=C$, where $C$ would be an invertible matrix. From there, I'd say $B=DC^{-1}$, but I don't know what properties $D$ should have. What's more, I don't know how the Rank would play into this case.

So, my question would be, what is the most intuitive way of attacking this problem? Is there any special property I should recognize by just looking at the rank, besides it being surjective?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the map $x\mapsto Ax$ is surjective, there is an $x$ such that
$$Ax=\pmatrix{1\cr0\cr0\cr\vdots\cr}\ .$$
This $x$ will be the first column of your $B$, and similarly for the other columns.

Comment: The implication I need to prove is then, Let $A$ be a surjective linear transformation, then there exists some vector $v$ that belongs to $F^{n}$ s.t. $Av=e_i$, with $e_i$ being an element of the standard basis of $F^{m}$.?
And after that, I can extend the process for $m$ linearly independent column vectors, since the rank is $m$.

Comment: Re: your first sentence, there is nothing to prove, that is just what "surjective" means.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I got it after a while. One of the books I'm reading defines surjectivity as exactly Range=Codomain. Which of course is equivalent to the standard definition, but I got used to using the other one. I guess I should rely more on the formal one.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts :

1) There is a "standard" answer : take $B=A^+$, the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of $A$. See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse

This pseudo inverse is a classical operator in scientific languages like MatLab (operator "pinv").

2) Now that we have found one such submatrix $B=A^+$, it suffices to add to this matrix certain matrices to have all solutions. Here is how:

Consider for example the case of (rank 2) matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $C_k, k=1 \cdots 4$ be its columns. They are of course dependent; one can find 2 zero linear combinations, for example

$(1)C_1+(-2)C_2+(1)C_3+(0)C_4=0$ and $(2)C_1+(-3)C_2+(0)C_3+(1)C_4=0$

But these coefficients are part of the kernel of $A$. It means that matrix $C$ defined, for any multipliers $a$ and $b$ by

$$C=\begin{bmatrix} a(1) & b(2) \\ a(-2) & b(-3) \\ a(1) & b(0) \\ a(0) & b(1) \end{bmatrix}$$

will be such that $AC=0$. So, if you have a solution $B$ to $AB=I$, $B+C$ is also  such that $A(B+C)=I$ (this "kernel adding"  is found in many issues, e.g., in differential equations, every time because an affine issue is transformed into a vectorial issue).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand it. It's similar to the case where, for example, you have the solutions to the homogeneous linear differential equation associated to a non-homogeneous, so you just need to find the missing elements of the basis.
I'm trying to see if I can get comfortable with the idea of semi-inverses, albeit I'm pretty sure I need to study a lot more abstract algebra before I get to it.
Thanks for the alternative way of proving it. I had been dabling with extending matrices, but I hadn't seen if it was justifiable or not.